# Pandas merge using dfA column == dfB index

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, left-join

How to merge (left join) using column `value` from dataframe A and index of dataframe B?

For example:

```
>>> A              >>> B
    lkey value         rkey value
0   foo  1         0   foo  5
1   bar  2         1   bar  6
2   baz  3         2   qux  7
3   foo  4         3   bar  8
```

to get:

```
   lkey  value_x  rkey  value_y
 0 foo   1        bar   6
 1 bar   2        qux   7
 2 baz   3        bar   8
 3 foo   4        NaN   NaN
```

Comment: The question [Pandas merge on index column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889486/pandas-merge-on-index-column) is a duplicate of this (albeit less clearly-written). I suggest this should be the canonical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `left_on` and `right_index` to do the merging, like:

```
m = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, right_index = True, left_on='value')
```