# Pandas merge on index column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [88]: c
Out[88]: 
                       Address    Name
CustomerID                            
10            Address for Mike    Mike
11          Address for Marcia  Marcia

In [89]: c.index
Out[89]: Int64Index([10, 11], dtype='int64', name='CustomerID')

In [90]: orders
Out[90]: 
   CustomerID   OrderDate
0          10  2014-12-01
1          11  2014-12-01
2          10  2014-12-01

In [91]: orders.index
Out[91]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

In [92]: c.merge(orders)
---------------------------
MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on
```

So panda can't merge if **index** column in one *dataframe* has the same name as another column in a second dataframe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify how to join the table. By default, `merge` will choose common column name as merge key. For your case,

```
c.merge(orders, left_index=True, right_on='CustomID')
```

Also, read the docs of [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) please.
Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: thx, I'm reading various books right now, a lot of info :) thanks Rojeer!

Answer (score 3):

The `join` method does a left join by default (`how='left')` and joins on the indices of the dataframes.  So set the index of the `orders` dataframe to `CustomerId` and then join.

```
# Create sample data.
orders = pd.DataFrame(
    {'CustomerID': [10, 11, 10],
     'OrderDate': ['2014-12-01', '2014-12-01', '2014-12-01']})    
c = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Address': ['Address for Mike', 'Address for Marcia'], 
     'Name': ['Mike', 'Marcia']},
    index=pd.Index([10, 11], dtype='int64', name='CustomerID'))

# Join.
>>> c.join(orders.set_index('CustomerID'))
                       Address    Name   OrderDate
CustomerID                                        
10            Address for Mike    Mike  2014-12-01
10            Address for Mike    Mike  2014-12-01
11          Address for Marcia  Marcia  2014-12-01
```

Alternatively, this `merge` will give you the same result.  Here, you are joining on the index of `c` (the left dataframe) and on the `CustomerID` column in the right dataframe.  Ensure to specify `how='left'` to only join items from the right dataframe to all of the records on the left (leaving an equivalent number of rows matching the length of `c`).  The default behavior for `merge` is an inner join, wherebe the result only includes those records from `c` that find a match in `orders` (although this could be your desired result).

```
c.merge(orders, left_index=True, right_on='CustomerID', how='left')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the index:

```
c.reset_index().merge(orders)
```