# Map a pandas column with column names

Tags: pandas, join, merge, left-join

I have two data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

# Column contains column name
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Column": pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']),
                    "Item": pd.Series(['x', 'y', 'z', 'x']),
                    "Result": pd.Series([3, 4, 5, 6])})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": pd.Series(['x', 'n', 'n']),
                    "b": pd.Series(['x', 'y', 'n']),
                    "c": pd.Series(['x', 'z', 'n'])})
```

How can I add "Result" to df2 based on the "Item" in the "Column"? 
Expected dataframe df2 is:

```
a  b  c  Result
-  -  -  ------
x  x  x  3
n  y  z  4
n  n  n  null
```

How can the above question be a duplicate of 3 questions, 2 of which are marked with an 'or' by @smci?

Comment: This is called 'merge` or 'join'. Specifically a left-join on df2 of df1's `Result` column. And you are trying to join on `df1.Column` == `df2.index`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas merge only certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978133/python-pandas-merge-only-certain-columns)

Comment: @iDrwish please repost your comment and edit a clarification into the question title and text. To make it clear why this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: So actually this is a **duplicate of [Pandas merge using dfA column == dfB index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802023/pandas-merge-using-dfa-column-and-dfb-index)** or [Pandas merge on index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889486/pandas-merge-on-index-column) or similar. I can't change my vote now, but please vote for those. (The only nuance is OP only wants to merge the `Result` column, but that's trivial.)

Comment: @smci can you give the command to do this merge / join pls?

Comment: I already did in the questions I cited above (of which this is a duplicate). Did you read them?

Comment: I read but could not understand. There are 3 links given and each has a different dataset.

Comment: reservoirinvest, doesn't matter what the indidivual dataset looks like, really. Each of those has a) two dataframes: `df1,df2` (or `dfA,dfB`) b) the column you want to merge on, e.g. `df1.merge(right_index = True, left_on='Column'))` and c)  the column you want to slice e.g. `'Result'`. Ok? Please read the answers to each, try them in your Python session and it should become clear. This really is a duplicate and we are obligated to close duplicates to prevent the site being flooded with the same questions over and over again. If you still don't understand, edit your new code into your question

Comment: @smci df1.merge(right_index = True, left_on = 'Column') gives _positional argument error_. df1.merge(df2, right_index = True, left_on = 'Column') gives an empty dataframe.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the twists; this is a lot more complicated than at first glance. `df1` is in long-form, it has two entries for 'b'. so it needs to be stacked/unstacked/pivoted into a 3x4 table where 'Column' becomes the index, and the values from 'Item' = 'x'/'y'/'z' give a full 3x3 matrix with NaN for missing values, and the 4th column will be 'Result'. ...

Comment: ...then somehow we use the columns of `df2` (how exactly?) to join `Result` column from the full pivoted version of `df1`. It seems like we use the leftmost value of `df1['x','y','z']` which specifies a valid column name in `df2` to join the corresponding row from `df2` to get its `Result`. Does that sound right?

Comment: It's still unclear which column of df2 are we supposed to use as column-name into df1: the diagonal of df2? the first valid leftmost name in each row of df2? and is 'n' an explicit invalid sentinel (like NaN?), or just a column name which doesn't happen to exist in df1 (that's going to be a pain to code, we would have to try multiple joins and combine their output)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot more complicated than at first glance. df1 is in long-form, it has two entries for 'b'. So first it needs to be stacked/unstacked/pivoted into a 3x3 table of 'Result' where 'Column' becomes the index, and the values from 'Item' = 'x'/'y'/'z' are expanded to a full 3x3 matrix with NaN for missing values:

```
>>> df1_full = df1.pivot(index='Column', columns='Item', values='Result')
Item      x    y    z
Column               
a       3.0  NaN  NaN
b       NaN  4.0  5.0
c       6.0  NaN  NaN
```

(Note the unwanted type-conversion to float, this is because numpy doesn't have NaN for integers, see [Issue 17013](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17013) in pre-pandas-0.22.0 versions. No problem, we'll just cast back to int at the end.)

Now we want to do `df1_full.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on=??)`

But first we need another trick/intermediate column to find the leftmost valid value in `df2` which corresponds to a valid column-name from `df1`; the value `n` is invalid, maybe we replace it with `NaN` to make life easier:

```
>>> df2.replace('n', np.NaN)
     a    b    c
0    x    x    x
1  NaN    y    z
2  NaN  NaN  NaN

>>> df2_nan.columns = [0,1,2]

     0    1    2
0    x    x    x
1  NaN    y    z
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

And we want to successively test `df2`'s columns from L-to-R as to whether their value is `in df1_full.columns`, similar to [Computing the first non-missing value from each column in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309514/computing-the-first-non-missing-value-from-each-column-in-a-dataframe)
, except testing successive columns (`axis=1`). Then store that intermediate column-name into a new column, 'join_col' :

```
>>> df2['join_col'] = df2.replace('n', np.NaN).apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1)

   a  b  c join_col
0  x  x  x        a
1  n  y  z        b
2  n  n  n     None
```

Actually we want to index into the column-names of df1, but it blows up on the NaN:

```
>>> df1.columns[ df2_nan.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1) ]
```

(Well that's not exactly working, but you get the idea.)

Finally we do the merge `df1_full.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on='join_col')`. And maybe take the desired column slice `['a','b','c','Result']`. And cast `Result` back to int, or map 'Nan' -> 'null'.